# Random Sorting with Conditions with Spreadsheet (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to set up a spreadsheet that randomly sorts names. I've done this by using `rand()` and sorting that by smallest to largest. But how do I get it to check that in a 4 block that two names are not repeated. The names are taken from another part in the spreadsheet where the numbers are needed in correct order.

View of spreadsheet:
[image]

Comment: Clearly, since there are **8** Matts and only **5** groups, some groups must have repeated Matts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you're asking.

This formula will identify whether there are duplicate names in your groups of 4 rows:

`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(B1:B4,B1:B4))`

Paste this formula at the start of each group.  If the sum is greater than 4, there are duplicates.

[image]

I guess you can just keep sorting columns B:D until you get all 4's?  Good luck.

PS. If I've misunderstood your problem, let me know.

Comment: I was hoping for an automatic solution, but this will do